# How to check if image exists with given url?

Tags: jquery

I want to check if an image exists using jquery.

For example how do I check this image exists

```
http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png
```

the check must give me a 200 or status ok

--------------edited-------------------

```
var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
var imgcheck = imgsrc.width;


if (imgcheck==0) {
alert("You have a zero size image");
} else { //do rest of code }
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: You are quite within your rights to post and accept an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use the [`error`](http://api.jquery.com/error/) handler like this:

```
$('#image_id').error(function() {
  alert('Image does not exist !!');
});
```

If the image cannot be loaded (for example, because it is not present at the supplied URL), the alert is displayed:

**Update:**

I think using:

```
$.ajax({url:'somefile.dat',type:'HEAD',error:do_something});
```

would be enough to check for a 404.

**More Readings:**

- http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro3/

**Update 2:**

Your code should be like this:

```
$(this).error(function() {
  alert('Image does not exist !!');
});
```

No need for these lines and that won't check if the remote file exists anyway:

```
var imgcheck = imgsrc.width;    

if (imgcheck==0) {
  alert("You have a zero size image");
} else { 
  //execute the rest of code here 
}
```

Comment: @sAc I dont have an id for the images, just want to check if file is present, else move on to execute the remaining code

Comment: @Jean: Please post your code in your question to see what you have or how you need this.

Comment: If you take a look at this url http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png , if the image is present, it must give me the size, or a status 200/ok

Comment: @sAc  the imgsrc.width does not seem to be working.  I am using the image url to obtain the width...The image url is being passed, checked by alert

Comment: In most cases you will want to add async:false to the AJAX call, otherwise it will return at some random interval and can cause erratic results in your scripting.

Comment: It works! However, I ran into a No Access-Control-Allow-Origin  problem when using the method, anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 34):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.example.com/somefile.ext',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function(){
            //do something depressing
    },
    success: function(){
            //do something cheerful :)
    }
});
```

from: http://www.ambitionlab.com/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-using-jquery-2010-01-06

Comment: WARNING: You'll get error: [XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://not.on.your.domain.com/someimg.jpg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.]  So this is only a good choice if the image is on your server.

Answer (score 14):

if it doesnt exist load default image or handle error

```
$('img[id$=imgurl]').load(imgurl, function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") 
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/DEFAULT.JPG');
    else
        $(this).attr('src', imgurl);
    });
```

Comment: This is the right answer, you can also use `$('<img>').load(url ...`

Answer (score 5):

## Use Case

```
$('#myImg').safeUrl({wanted:"http://example/nature.png",rm:"/myproject/images/anonym.png"});
```

## API :

```
$.fn.safeUrl=function(args){
  var that=this;
  if($(that).attr('data-safeurl') && $(that).attr('data-safeurl') === 'found'){
        return that;
  }else{
       $.ajax({
    url:args.wanted,
    type:'HEAD',
    error:
        function(){
            $(that).attr('src',args.rm)
        },
    success:
        function(){
             $(that).attr('src',args.wanted)
             $(that).attr('data-safeurl','found');
        }
      });
   }


 return that;
};
```

---

Note : `rm` means here risk managment .

---

## Another Use Case :

```
$('#myImg').safeUrl({wanted:"http://example/1.png",rm:"http://example/2.png"})
.safeUrl({wanted:"http://example/2.png",rm:"http://example/3.png"});
```

- '`http://example/1.png`' :  if not exist '`http://example/2.png`'
- '`http://example/2.png`' :  if not exist '`http://example/3.png`'

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/):

```
// when the DOM is ready
$(function () {
  var img = new Image();
  // wrap our new image in jQuery, then:
  $(img)
    // once the image has loaded, execute this code
    .load(function () {
      // set the image hidden by default    
      $(this).hide();
      // with the holding div #loader, apply:
      $('#loader')
        // remove the loading class (so no background spinner), 
        .removeClass('loading')
        // then insert our image
        .append(this);
      // fade our image in to create a nice effect
      $(this).fadeIn();
    })
    // if there was an error loading the image, react accordingly
    .error(function () {
      // notify the user that the image could not be loaded
    })
    // *finally*, set the src attribute of the new image to our image
    .attr('src', 'images/headshot.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 3.0 [removed](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed) `.error`. Correct syntax is now

```
$(this).on('error', function(){
    console.log('Image does not exist: ' + this.id); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle the lazy loading with image existence check I followed this in jQuery-

```
$('[data-src]').each(function() {
  var $image_place_holder_element = $(this);
  var image_url = $(this).data('src');
  $("<div class='hidden-classe' />").load(image_url, function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (!(status == "error")) {
      $image_place_holder_element.removeClass('image-placeholder');
      $image_place_holder_element.attr('src', image_url);
    }
  }).remove();
});
```

Reason: if I am using `$image_place_holder_element.load()` method it will be adding the response to the element, so random div and removing it appeared me a good solution. Hope it works for someone trying to implement lazy loading along with url check.