# Is there any way to have an image on an html page default to another image if the original source isn't there?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, image

I have a website with images of people.  Sometimes the server with all of the images goes down and my website shows broken image links.  I wanted to see if there is anyway on a webpage to have the following logic where you src one picture but if it doesn't load properly then default to another picture as a backup?

I am fine if it requires js or jquery, etc . .

Comment: I think that you want the solution in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: Are you serving up images in a way that the asp.net-mvc tag is relevant, such as `return File(...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it with css. Just do something like this on an image class. And set it to the html  tag

```
.myimage{
    background: url("images/default.png");
```

}

Or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381663/check-if-image-exists-with-given-url-using-jquery) out.