# Call when a image loads in an <img> or verify a picture URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a form with some inputs, etc... And one of them asks for a URL of a picture, and I want the browser to verify if the url or the pic given is active and working.

So I have an `img` element next to the url input, and when this input is blurred, the `src` attribute of that img changes with javascript automatically and is set to the url given. I want to determine if the image loaded properly, or it isn't working. I don't know if there is a function to do that without the img element, but please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onerror` and `onload` events on the `img` DOM element.  Just make sure to set the callbacks before you actually set the `src` property of the image. The following code can be used to check to see if a URL is a valid image URL.  You can use similar code to check if an image has loaded into an existing `img` element (just select that element instead of creating a new one).

```
var checkImage = function (url) {

  var image = document.createElement('img');

  image.onerror = function () {
      // image has failed to load
      console.log('url is not valid');
  };

  image.onload = function () {
      // image has loaded successfully
      console.log('url is valid');
  };

  image.src = url;
};
```

Comment: How can i use this code and what should i do with the img elem to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.example.com/yourimage.jpg',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function(){
            //do sth to handle error
           },
    success: function(){
            //do sth when load succeeded
           }
});
```

The above code should check errors, like 404, etc.

Also, you might want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3381694/786796).

Comment: This doesn't ensure that the url points to a valid image though, just that it is a valid url.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/0kwsetp1/1/

```
$("input").on("blur change", function () {
    var image = $("#the-image"),
        $this = $(this),
        string = $this.val();

    image[0].onerror = function () {
        alert("Image could not be loaded");
    };
    image.attr("src", string);
});
```

Thanks to Bill for guiding me to `onerror`.