# JavaScript/jQuery best way to catch GET 404 error (image loading)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote simple code to check is image loaded

```
imageLoadErrorCheck: function() {
    $('img').on('error', function() {
        $(this).addClass('img_errorShowInfo');
        $(this).prop('src', '/assets/default/img/404.png');
    });
},
```

but somehow in some cases this code is not working approx in 1 on 20 refreshes it's not triggering (I'm checking now in Chrome only).

Is any better way to recognize when an image was not loaded?
E.g. console always throwing GET 404 error, maybe is a way to catch this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381663/check-if-image-exists-with-given-url-using-jquery

Comment: Where is the script situated? The event could have been triggered before the listerner started.

Comment: script is called on `$(document).ready` and `$(document)ajaxComplete`

Comment: If I remember correctly the images start loading before the document ready event fires, if you put the body of the function into the header it should work always.