# $.parseHTML().error() is not a function error when dynamically creating DOM elements

Tags: jquery, html, html-parsing

I'm creating `img` elements using [`$.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/), from a dynamic string
so I need to check if the `img` was successfully created with the given `src`
ps: the image is hosted on the same server not an external link.

```
<img id='lorem' src='someURL'>
```

I used [`.error()`](https://api.jquery.com/error/) methode as I fould in this [**Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381663/how-to-check-if-image-exists-with-given-url).
I got it to work as expecteced, by using this :

```
$('#lorem').error(function(){alert('img does not exist')})
```

then it doesn't work when I start using [`$.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) again
the console says `$.parseHTML(...).error is not a function`
so I use `jQuery.type()` to debug and I get an array ! wich is not expected because I created only one element.
and when I try to access only one by one memeber of the array it still doesn't work
any suggestions ? thanks in advance.

Comment: @DinoMyte why all this hate ?

Comment: No hate bro, just correct the spelling to make it easier to understand the title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `$.parseHTML` returns an array, which has no `error` method. You need to create an actual DOMElement before you can hook an `error` event handler to it.

From the look of your code, `$.parseHTML` is redundant as you can just create the element normally, like this:

```
$('<img src="invalidURL" />').error(function() {
    alert('img does not exist');
})
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bn5gtqum/)

Comment: thanks it works, i thought it would return a DOMelement as it should since it says pars..HTML, but it returned an array in deed